# How to calculate the distance between multiple coordinates in a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
< script >
  const start = document.querySelector("#start");
const stop = document.querySelector("#stop");
const calculate = document.querySelector("#calculate");

//  const coordinates = []; 
// const coordinates1 = [];
var lat_1 = [];
var lon_1 = [];
var lat_2 = [];
var lon_2 = [];

start.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data => {
      console.log(data);
      lat_1.push([data.coords.latitude]);
      lon_1.push([data.coords.longitude]);
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        "lat1",
        JSON.stringify(lat_1)
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        "lon1",
        JSON.stringify(lon_1)
      );

    },
    (error) => console.log(error), {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }

  );
});

stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data => {
      console.log(data);
      lat_2.push([data.coords.latitude]);
      lon_2.push([data.coords.longitude]);
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        "lat2",
        JSON.stringify(lat_2)
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        "lon2",
        JSON.stringify(lon_2)
      );

    },
    (error) => console.log(error), {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }

  );
});

//Converts coordinates in degrees to radians.
function toRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.coords.length - 1; i++) {
  distanceTotal += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coords[i], coords[i + 1]);
}
// let sum = 0;
//for (let i = 0; i = 100; i++) {



//Harvensine Formula
function calculateDistance() {
  //Get values of our inputs
  var late_1 = window.localStorage.getItem("lat1");
  var lat1 = JSON.parse(late_1);
  var long_1 = window.localStorage.getItem("lon1");
  var lon1 = JSON.parse(long_1);
  var late_2 = window.localStorage.getItem("lat2");
  var lat2 = JSON.parse(late_2);
  var long_2 = window.localStorage.getItem("lon2");
  var lon2 = JSON.parse(long_2);






  // Radius of earth, KM 
  var radiusOfEarth = 6371;
  var lattitudeDifference = lat2 - lat1;
  var dLat = toRad(lattitudeDifference);
  var longitudeDifference = lon2 - lon1;
  var dLon = toRad(longitudeDifference);
  /*
  a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
  c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
  d = R ⋅ c
  where φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius
  Assumes that the earth radius is 6,371 KM
  */
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var distance = radiusOfEarth * c;
  distance = parseFloat(distance).toFixed(2);
  var distanceInMiles = 0.62137119 * distance
  distanceInMiles = parseFloat(distanceInMiles).toFixed(2);
  //document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = distance + " km, or " + distanceInMiles + "mi.";
  //sum + distance[i];
  console.log(distance, distanceInMiles);

}
//}







<
/script>
```

I have a code to calculate distance between two coordinates, but I want to calculate the distance between multiple coordinates and I tried loop over an array using Harvensine Formula, but I couldn't do it, Please help me.

> emphasized text
> Hello, I want to calculate the distance between multiple coordinates in a button click, could you please help me out, I have attached my code below. I mean, how do I loop over an array using Harvensine Formula.

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. Perhaps you could explain it as *I have this ____ and I am trying to do _____ but I am stuck doing ____*

Comment: I have edited my question, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to put more effort in. Show what you tried, what you expected and what was different from expected along with any errors. Include some sample data to test that code against. Take some time to thoroughly read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Hey bro, is that possible for you to help me out by making a Skype call or discord chat, I would really appreciate it.